# Modelling Diode current with ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, simulation, electromagnetism

I want to write ODE system for simulating following electrical circuit:
[image]

At each small step `dt` i just do euler integration.
I only know ODE for leaky capacitor:

`Vc = Vc + dt * (Ic - Vc*gLeak)/Cmembrane`

Inductor formula itself is `V = L * dI/dt`. But i dont know ODE for diode with inductor in series. 
Could you help me a bit?

Comment: This question seems better placed (and perhaps already answered) at [Electrical engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=diode+model).

Comment: @ccorn Unfortunately i dislike and banned that site, there are bad people. Btw, it is not about electrical engineering. I may also draw some gears, springs and turn it to mechanical analogy. Or i can draw water pipe, a valve and flywheel. Or use thermodynamics, acoustics or whatever terms you like to describe rectification, along with kinetic energy damping/accumulation processes and relations. Should i post it to all those forums, or leave it math-related?

Comment: This is fairly basic modeling and does belong at the electrical engineering site.

Comment: @copper.hat If this seems very basic to you, may you just write down answering formula? And again. I can reword this in terms of water pressure and flux. Diode is *one-way valve*, and inductor is a *flywheel with inertia inside a pipe*. Should i post this to water-pipes engeneering site as well? Question was about correct ODE for that series of those 2 elements.

Comment: You are missing the point. This is a site to help people with questions about mathematics, not to respond to requests to model dynamical systems. Furthermore, there is not a simple 'here's the equation' sort of answer. The system above is typically modeled by an implicit ODE of the form $\phi(\dot{x},x) = 0$, where $x$ are the state variables (which would represent, at minimum, the capacitor & inductor states above).